# Host Web Serivces on ColdFusion Builder's Local Server

Tags: apache, coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I'm using ColdFusion Builder 2016 with the built-in local server, and I have certain web services that I'd like to host. These web services are represented by `asmx` files however these files basically only have one line while the generated `DLL` file holds the actual function definitions.

**UserService.asmx**

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" 
    CodeBehind="UserService.asmx.cs" 
    Class="External.Requests.UserService" %>
```

This works perfectly in IIS, however I can't seem to find a way to accomplish the same thing in ColdFusion builder without having to setup an IIS website. In reality the the built-in server in ColdFusion Builder uses Apache.

Is this even possible?

Comment: That is a .NET C# web service which requires IIS to run. You maybe able to get it working on apache if you use mod_mono (www.mono-project.com)

Comment: @haxtbh Right you are, mind posting this as the answer so I can mark it as resolved.